# c++ array error while executing

Tags: c++

When i run my program i keep getting this error. The program will still execute and run and display the correct nymbers in the terminal, but I need it to ouput another file and put them on there. please help new to c++.

> bash-3.2$ g++ -Wall 1.cpp
>   1.cpp: In function 'std::string IP_Calculation(std::string*, std::string, int)':1.cpp:71:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

---

```
string IP_Calculation(string IP[], string Company_name, int total_IPS)
{
    string temp = "";
    char buf[80];
    char buf2[80];
    if (total_IPS != 0)
    {
        int UniqueIP_count = total_IPS;

        for (int i = 0; i < total_IPS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < total_IPS; j++)
            {

                if (strcmp(IP[i].c_str(), IP[j].c_str()) == 0)
                {
                    if (strcmp(IP[i].c_str(), "") == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    IP[j] = "";
                    UniqueIP_count--;

                }

            }

        }

        temp = print_array(IP);

        cout << Company_name << " | Number of Visitor: " << total_IPS
                << "| Unique         Visitors: " << UniqueIP_count << endl;
        //cout<<Company_name<<" | Number of Visitor: "<<buf <<"| Unique  Visitors:      "<<UniqueIP_count<<endl;
        cout << temp;
        sprintf(buf, "%d", total_IPS);
        sprintf(buf2, "%d", UniqueIP_count);
        // return temp=Company_name+" | Number of Visitor: "+( total_IPS) +"|      Unique   Visitors: "+to_string( UniqueIP_count)+"\n"+temp+"\n";
        return temp = Company_name + " | Number of Visitor: " + buf
                + "| Unique   Visitors:   " + buf2 + "\n" + temp + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: rest of the code i dont know why it wont appear

Comment: cout<<Company_name<<" | Number of Visitor: "<<total_IPS <<"| Unique         Visitors: "<<UniqueIP_count<<endl;
    //cout<<Company_name<<" | Number of Visitor: "<<buf <<"| Unique  Visitors:      "<<UniqueIP_count<<endl;
    cout<<temp;
  sprintf( buf, "%d", total_IPS );
  sprintf( buf2, "%d", UniqueIP_count );
  // return temp=Company_name+" | Number of Visitor: "+( total_IPS) +"|      Unique   Visitors: "+to_string( UniqueIP_count)+"\n"+temp+"\n";
  return temp=Company_name+" | Number of Visitor: "+buf +"| Unique   Visitors:   "+buf2+"\n"+temp+"\n";
 }
}

Comment: Edit that in, readable formatting is strongly preferred.

Comment: That is not an error message. It is a warning. The warning message effectively says this: "Dude, you said this function returns a `string` but you are not returning anything at all. Whats up with that?" Also, you need to clean up formatting of that question. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help.

Comment: Add proper indentations and then check http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code.

Comment: @crayzeewulf sorry this is due before 8 and I have no idea what's going on. Can you please help me

Comment: @ChrisScott The last three comments suggest cleaning up the formatting. Please start there. The warning message you provided occurs when you compile the program not when you run the program (as your first sentence seems to imply). If you just need to put the output of the program into a file, you can simply use [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). For example, if your program is called `my_program` and you want to save its output to a file named `my_output.txt`, run the command: `my_program > my_output.txt`. Otherwise, explain what you need.

Comment: @leoxs how could you edit that and not fix the gonzo code formatting?

Comment: The error message says the function can reach the end without a `return` statement. I see an `if` with a `return` statement in it. I do not see an `else` with a `return` statement to cover the other possibility or a `return` at the end of the function just to make sure.

Comment: Why do you assign a variable in your `return` statements? Since the function stops when it returns, what's the point of assigning a variable at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The warning is because the function is declared to return a `string`, but the compiler has determined that it's possible that it may not do that. You have a `return` statement that returns a string in your `if` statement. But when `Total_IPs` is `0`, you won't execute that block of code, and you'll never execute that `return` statement. Since you don't have an `else` block, you'll just exit the function, without returning a string as required. You need to change it to:

```
if (Total_IPs != 0) {
    ...
} else {
    return "";
}
```

so that you return something when the condition fails.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I understand. You want to write the output in a file? Something like this should work:

```
int writeFile () 
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the warning he's getting.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I don't answer that because someone do that already, so I helped only with the other question. Or what I think is another question.